# what does the ```time.perf_counter()``` command do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not understand what the `time.perf_counter ()` command does.
Here is the code which includes the command `time.perf_counter()`

```
import random
num_nums = 100
start_time = time.perf_counter()
numbers = str(random.randint(1,100))
for i in range(num_nums):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    numbers += ',' + str(num)
end_time = time.perf_counter()
td1 = end_time - start_time
start_time = time.perf_counter()
numbers=[]
for i in range(num_nums):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    numbers.append(str(num))
numbers = ', '.join(numbers)
end_time = time.perf_counter()
td2 = end_time - start_time
start_time = time.perf_counter()
numbers = [str(random.randint(1,100)) for i in range(1,num_nums)]
numbers = ', '.join(numbers)
end_time = time.perf_counter()
td3 = end_time - start_time
print('''Number of numbers: {:,}
Time Delta 1: {}
Time Delta 2: {}
Time Delta 3: {}'''.format(num_nums, td1, td2, td3))
```

**An here is the result**

````
Time Delta 1: 0.0003232999999909225
Time Delta 2: 0.00016150000010384247
Time Delta 3: 0.0003734999997959676```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the definition here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter

The call is gathering the amount of time that has taken place between 2 consecutive calls of `time.perf_counter` and will be with extreme precision.

Comment: perhaps you can type the answer down here